# Do chips in a stained floor reveal differently-colored, unstained wood?

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor

I'm replacing floor in my house and I have made up mind about going with solid wood flooring.

I also want it stained in dark shades, but since this is not a natural colour of the wood, I was wondering, what happens to any chips that will inevitably happen in the future? Does lighter wood appear through them?

One of the advantages of solid wood that convinced me is that they would last longer and could be sanded/repaired. But if stained wood would make the repair harder I might consider a lighter shade.

Comment: Another consideration for dark stains on hardwood floors is they tend to show dirt and debris more. Logically it depends on what color your local dirt/debris is; but in my experience (one house with light/natural wood floors and another with dark wood floors) is that the darker stain shows it much more. I have heard anecdotally from others that really dark or black floors show it even more. I believe the issue is that it starts to show “dust” more prominently forcing the need to mop more regularly.

Answer (score 1):

Yep. If they bug you you can touch up the chips with stain as needed until you refinish the floor completely someday. For minor chips it's not really necessary to also apply sealer, but you could.